# Could not find method sourceCompatibility() for arguments on root project

Tags: java, gradle, javacompiler

I would like to define *source* and *target compatibility* for a [Java library](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/HalfnarpClient) which is built with Gradle. Therefore, I add the following block [as documented for the Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile).

```
apply plugin: 'java'

// ...

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

When I assemble the project the following **error** occurs:

> Could not find method sourceCompatibility() for arguments [1.7] on root project

---

#### Related

- [How can I set the compileOptions for my Gradle Java plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593500/how-can-i-set-the-compileoptions-for-my-gradle-java-plugin)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to pass the values of the wrong type. `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` should be the Strings, but `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` is not a String, but just enumiration with overrided `toString()` method. That is why you've got `for arguments [1.7]` in the exception text. Just try to do it like:

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7.toString()
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7.toString()
}
```

or

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility "$JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7"
    targetCompatibility "$JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7"
}
```

Or just move it out out of `compileJava` closure to the script body, as it usually used, like:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```

Comment: ... or just simply write "1.7" instead of using the `JavaVersion` enumeration.

Comment: @Stanislav Your last suggestion `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 ..` does not work for me and produces the **same error** as before. The 1st and 2nd suggestions work although the former produces an **inspection warning** in IntelliJ 14.1.5. `... cannot be applied to (String)`. So, I might use the 2nd approach.

Comment: @JJD curiously, it is working for me, with gradle 2.6 and Intellij 14.1.3, if to place it out of any tasks closure

Comment: @Stanislav Please try to build [the project](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/HalfnarpClient) on the command line via `./gradlew clean assemble` - that is what fails in my case.

Comment: @JJD my mistake, since we set the property out of configuration closure, we have to provide `=`, so I updated my answer. I just downloaded your project and added to the build script root `sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` and `targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` and it was successfully built with gradlew.

Comment: @Stanislav When I use the corrected assignment `sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` then IntelliJ states `Assignment is not used.` and renders a curly underline for `sourceCompatibility` to visually indicate the warning.

Comment: @JJD you can ignore it, seems, that Idea doesn't know, that they are used in some additional plugin. Just to check, whether is option accepted by gradle java plugin, modify it as follows `sourceCompatibility = "wrongVersion"` to make the value equals to `wrongVersion` string. Your build will fail, because gradle could not determine java version. If you want to prevent idea to underline this properties, just modify some task, to print this values as additional info to the user during configuration phase.

Comment: I think I will use `compileJava { sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 }` which combines the advantages of all the mentioned variants.