# Showing a message whether the mapstruct annotation processor creates files or not - preferable for my custom 'generateMappers' task

Tags: gradle, mapstruct

Courtesy of M.Ricciuti who answered my initial ['Migrating from Gradle 4 to 5. How to get mapstruct 1.20.final working with it'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170222/migrating-from-gradle-4-to-5-how-to-get-mapstruct-1-20-final-working-with-it/56171049#56171049) question I've an addition question. Created a new new thread because 'add comment' does not allow me enough characters/text.

I would like to have a  Gradle 'generateMappers' task to generate the mapstruct source files AND display a message when the sources are generated and preferable one which tells me that nothing is generated because it wasn't needed.

In the old situation we had a generateMappers task which used mapstruct to generate source files AND display a message when the files were created. Now its basically empty.

```
task generateMappers (type: JavaCompile, dependsOn: compileJava) {
        doFirst {
                println "\tGenerating mapper classes"
        }

        doLast {
                println "\tMapping classes generated"
        }
}

Gradlew -i generateMappers reveals the following. 
> Task :eu.myfirm.rest:generateMappers NO-SOURCE
Skipping task ':eu.myfirm.rest:generateMappers' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
:eu.myfirm.rest:generateMappers (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.[enter link description here][1]
NOTE: > Task :eu.myfirm.rest:compileJava FROM-CACHE does trigger correctly ONLY when the sources are not there.
```

By changing the task into 'task generateMappers {...}' I ALWAY get a message - even when no new files are generated because nothing has changed in the mappers. Gradlew --info reveals

```
> Task :eu.myfirm.rest:generateMappers
Custom actions are attached to task ':eu.myfirm.rest:generateMappers'.
Caching disabled for task ':eu.myfirm.rest:generateMappers' because:
  Caching has not been enabled for the task
Task ':eu.myfirm.rest:generateMappers' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
        Generating mapper classes
        Mapping classes generated
```

Its wrong because caching is disabled and I know this is only cosmetic because whether the sources are there or not I will always get this message.

**I've this feeling I'm on the WRONG track and I somehow have to hook into the  annotationProcessor** to get the required two messages BUT I also would like to have a seperate 'generateMappers' task to call. Any further hints/pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there something we could do from MapStruct side? We recently added some rudimentary tracing functionality (target 1.4): https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1741. Might that offer some help?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Checked the PR and the other logging related ones. Not sure how additional logging (always good) could help me in this case. Perhaps I'm missing something, could you could explain further?

My Gradle knowledge is limited tbh but to me it looks more of a Gradle, annotationProcessor massaging issue - getting settings right.

Comment: Well. I'm not a Gradle expert either :). But I reckon its helpful to see if / what MapStruct generates. But you are right.. It seems more a Gradle than a MapStruct issue. MapStruct just relies on standard java apt to do its job.

Comment: Actually I didn't get it to work with apt (original mentioned thread) but got it working with Gradle's annotationProcessor. Hoping that a Gradle expert is reading this and can come up with a solution/hints/pointers. Still your effort is very much appreciated.

Comment: Anyone any hints/pointers.....